# What is the name for this rhetorical technique?

Tags: rhetoric

What is it called when person A makes an argument, then person B picks on a minor error in A's argument (such as a typo or misattribution of a quote) and uses this small error to argue that everything A says cannot be trusted and (by implication) must be false?

The closest I've got is "straw man", but that isn't quite right, since in this case the error is genuine.

I feel this technique must have a name, since it seems to be incredibly common in real-world debate!

Comment: Generally just *nitpicking*, *missing the forest for the trees*.

Comment: This is a key legal technique; if a witness has tripped up in one place, the rest of their testimony can be put into doubt. Perhaps there is a legal term for it?

Comment: I'm almost certain that this exact question has been asked here before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_fallacy):

> "Argument from fallacy is the formal fallacy of analyzing an argument and inferring that, since it contains a fallacy, its conclusion must be false. It is also called argument to logic (argumentum ad logicam), fallacy fallacy, fallacist's fallacy, and bad reasons fallacy."

Comment: +1. Depending on what is picked on, it might also be [cherry picking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking) or possibly [witness impeachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_impeachment) . Presumably, whether you think it's a logical fallacy or a legitimate impeachment will depend on the probative value of the error (e.g. a singular error introduced by a third party vs. a symptom of a wider pattern of sloppiness in record keeping) and which side of the case you're on.

Comment: That's the one, thank you! And thank you for the comment @1006a.